# Which material has the lowest Young's modulus?

Tags: solid-state-physics, elasticity, solid-mechanics

I guess some foams or elastomers would be the candidates. We are looking for materials with Young's modulus lower than 1 kPa. I also wonder how small it can be theoretically?

Comment: Don't know why there would be any lower limit on the Young's modulus if you are considering porous materials such as foams because in principle the density of the foam can always be made smaller and smaller. Probably the practical limit is that the strength and Young's modulus of the foam gets so small that it collapses on itself.

Comment: I would have thought this would be something Google would turn up on the first page, but instead I find "lowest of x" where the numbers in in the teen GPa. I saw a chart with various artificial "rubber" foams at "<0.01 MPa", but no details. I imagine the record would be for an aerogel, but even that turns up little that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

Hydrogels can have a Young's modulus as low as 5-10kPa easily (see for example gels of 1-2 percent agarose or alginate). You can probably get close to 1 kPa or less by lowering the percentage of agarose or alginate, but the gel may be prone to tearing and difficult to handle. You would probably need to experiment as these hydrogels are often used in biomedical applications, in which a minimum of physical integrity is required. Therefore, people usually use gels with larger Young's modulus than 1 kPa.

Comment: This is interesting. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Just google hydrogel young modulus and you should get a lot of papers. I used to work in a lab with people encapsulating cells in this kind of hydrogel. I also have a few clients now in that field. It's still a very active field.

Comment: To get you started ://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2034204/#!po=34.3023 although it is more concerned with the shear modulus.

Answer (score -2):

Water. Or more general, fluids.

Comment: We talk of elasticity of a fluid in terms of bulk modulus not young's modulus.